# Pathfinder 1x: Needing to upscale a dungeon

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, group-scaling

I have an old module (The Ring of Brodgar) I'm trying to drop into my campaign. We're using the Pathfinder 1e ruleset in a home brew world. I have no drow or underdark, but an ancient evil (essentially the father-god of all goblinoids including orcs, trolls, etc as well as all things demonic or aberrant) locked away which leaks its creations on the world.

The module is set in an empty dwarven fortress with what is basically a goblin town below it (unaware of the dwarven fortress above as its been effectively empty for 300 years, so no actual goblinkind can be used). The module has a tribe of [Grimlocks](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Grimlock) who have moved in with their [dire rat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/rat/dire-rat/) pets. Problem is, by the time the PCs made it to the module site, they're 7th level (silly me, I gave them a ghost town to tackle on the way).  I can probably upscale the grimlocks, maybe with [bugbears](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/bugbear/) or something similar but I'm stumped on their 'pets'.

Dire rats are just too weak for this group, and I think they could take a [swarm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/rat/rat-swarm/) easy (and I doubt ecology would feed a swarm). I either need a substitute critter that is a good monster pet that has the 'bite' to take  7th level party of 4, or suggestions on how to rebuild them into a balanced encounter.

The party (all 7th level) is comprised of an elf knight (fighter type), catfolk rogue, dragon (in human form) cleric following a homebrew dragon god, and human barbarian.

Comment: Could you add some details for us to help give some guidance from other GM's? Are you looking to keep Dire Rats, and how many encounters is this dungeon expected to be? How difficult do you need it to be/how optimized are your players? You may still be better off trying to get [ideas from a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), but we might be able to help if you have more specific criteria.

Comment: But, where are my manners? Welcome to the Stack Exchange, a Question:Answer site! We recommend all new users take our (very quick) [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) because we function a little different than most websites about the hobby.

Comment: not sure how much more specific I can get. The Grimlocks themselves may need to be upscaled or replaced. I can't use trolls, ogres, hob/goblins or orcs, because they're working together and if one of them in is the fortress, they'd have informed the town below. I need a monstrous humanoid, maybe CR 4-6 (so I can safely throw more than one at a time at them, cause maybe high numbers is the secret). The rats can be swapped for anything they'd keep as pets. I like the disease factor of the rats, but I'm not married to the idea that they have to be rat-like. Just... monstrous pets.

Comment: What module is this? We don't have any of the information.

Comment: Sandra, it's nice to have you here at RPG.SE! We'd gladly help you, but to do that, we need more information about your situation! If you are going to change an existing module, please tell us which module it is. I understand that it's a homebrew world, but it would still be cool to see the module if it's possible. Did I understand you correctly that you have originally intended to give PCs Dire Rats as enemies, but now the latter are too weak, and you want another monster as a replacement?

Comment: Once you get 15 reputation points, you'll be able to visit us in our [chat]. You can ask all your questions there, too. The chat is a lot better suited for back-and-forth discussions than our main Q&A website. :)

Comment: The Ring of Brodgar. The module is written for grimlocks and their pet dire rats, but they're just not enough unless I throw a swarm. I have 4 7th level characters.

Comment: Sandra, it's good that you've returned to give us that info! It would be even better if you could provide us with a link to that module. Also, now that you have 21 reputation points, it would really be a good idea to talk about your question in our [chat]. The folk there is very nice and helpful, and it *might* (though not necessarily *will*) be more faster to discuss all the details. After that, we can edit your question so that it can be successfully reopened and answered properly.

Comment: Also, you say that throwing a swarm of creatures might solve the problem -- why wouldn't you just do that? As far as I know, most characters have significant problems fighting swarms, and it can make a long and interesting fight if you do it correctly.

Comment: It would be nice to know the exact composition of your party, too. Tell us more about the characters; if you can, please provide their character sheets.

Comment: sorry, thought I did add the party but the comment seems to have vanished. I have an elven prince playing the knight errant (he's building towards an unknown destiny and must garner experience before he can be king, just not king of the kingdom he's from) with a rune sword, I have a catfolk rogue kid who was rescued from a dungeon they went into after running away from the circus who stole him as a kit;

Comment: there's the cleric (of a dragon god) who is a dragon in humanoid form adventuring to keep an eye on the human barbarian she befriended who wanted to go adventuring after his mother died (who actually rescued him from an assault that would have killed him as an infant. He really is a dragon who imprinted on the first sentient being he saw, changed into  something like her and just stayed that way. He doesn't even know he's a dragon yet.)

Comment: Exposition is great, but to be clear, that's an elf fighter, catfolk rogue, dragon(kin?) cleric (of bahumut or similar), and human barbarian?

Comment: I made a readability edit and added some of your commented information in. I tried to keep it in line with your intent, but if I've overstepped, you can re-edit it with the history button to the left of the question.

Comment: I'd also be interested to know, if you can't provide a link to the module, the encounters' supposed composition (how many grimlocks, what classes, etc) and how many encounters you intend for the dungeon to take. Also, is there any kind of time limit or is the party able to rest as much as they want?

Comment: not dragonkin. DRAGON. player is inexperienced and not using full potential however. Character is only Young Frost. There are supposed to be two dire rats in the kitchen. 7 CR 1 grimlocks, plue 4 females and their young. and the chief who's a 4th level fighter.

Comment: Googling didn't help me find the adventure itself, but I did find [this RPGGeek entry](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/255117/ring-brodgar) that seems to be about a 30-page PDF by Darren White.

Comment: yup, that's the one. I can't remember where I found it. Running today so...